# How to crawling & store multiple website?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want to make an webpage that crawling some webpage and intergate them.
I use node.js & vue.js.

with puppeteer & cheerio, I can crawling One Single page and store the data to my database.

My goal is crawling multiple webpage.

for example, there is a news page. Using puppeteer & cheerio, I got some title of article, the content of news. I can "SINGLE" page crawling.

but I don't know How can I crawling two page or more than that?
because The way of cheerio & puppeteer crawling, I have to check the webpage's css with web inspector. If I crawling multiple webpage, each of webpage have different css. So Should I code 5 different code for each of different webpage? If the webpage will be 10 or more?

this is my single webpage crawler.

```
router.get('/news', function(req, res, next) {
  (async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    });
  
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(process.env.VUE_APP_PROD_NEWS_DOMAIN);
    let previousHeight;

    while (true) {
      const currentHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
      if (currentHeight === previousHeight) {
        break;
      }
      previousHeight = currentHeight;
      await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
    }

    let content = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(content);
    const lists = $(".list-bigger-wrap");
    lists.each((index, list) => {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(list);
    });
    let news = []
    
    lists.each((index, list) => {
      imgsrc= $(list).find("img").attr('src');
      title = $(list).find(".list-bigger-txt p:first-child").text();
      peroid = $(list).find(".list-bigger-txt p:nth-child(2)").text();
      place = $(list).find(".list-bigger-txt p:nth-child(3)").text();
      exclusive = $(list).find(".list-bigger-txt p:nth-child(4)").text();

      concerts.push({
        imgsrc : imgsrc,
        title : title,
        peroid : peroid,
        place : place ,
        exclusive : exclusive
      })
      console.log({
        index, imgsrc , title, peroid, place , exclusive
      });
      
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      news : news
    })
    browser.close();
  })();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is related specifically to Vue.